# Signifié, signifiant et référence

Tags: sens

Voici un problème soulevant un point de langue intéressant:

```
Un paysan possède trois vaches, dix chevaux et vingt brebis.
Combien a-t-il de chevaux si les vaches sont également appelées "chevaux" ?
```

La réponse attendue est 10 car les vaches n'en deviennent pas des chevaux pour autant.

Certaines personnes me répondent 13 et justifient cela en additionnant les 3 nouveaux chevaux (les vaches baptisées chevaux) et les dix de base.

La première réponse semble avoir plus de sens en regard de la différence entre signifié et signifiant, mais je ne trouve pas de référence abondant dans un sens ou dans l'autre.

Voici une tentative de comprendre la phrase:

[image: Vache et cheval]

Dans un premier temps, on parle de cheval et de vache.
Nous associons donc bien le graphique "cheval" avec le concept d'un cheval.
De façon analogue pour "vache".

```
Un paysan possède trois vaches, dix chevaux et vingt brebis.
Combien a-t-il de chevaux si les vaches sont également appelées "c̲h̲e̲v̲a̲u̲x̲" ?
```

Ici on répond 10 car "chevaux" réfère au premier concept et n'est "redéfinit" qu'après.

On peut aussi prendre la phrase ainsi:

```
Un paysan possède trois vaches, dix c̲h̲e̲v̲a̲u̲x̲ et vingt brebis.
Combien a-t-il de c̲h̲e̲v̲a̲u̲x̲ si les vaches sont également appelées "c̲h̲e̲v̲a̲u̲x̲" ?
```

Ce qui s'est passé est un genre de rétroaction. Mais dans ce cas, seul 10 convient puisqu'en fait dans les 10 chevaux, il y a 3 vaches. Comme ce serait le cas si on écrivait : "il y a dix chiens et 3 bergers allemands".

On peut finalement interpréter la phrase ainsi :

```
Un paysan possède trois vaches, dix chevaux et vingt brebis.
Combien a-t-il de c̲h̲e̲v̲a̲u̲x̲ si les vaches sont également appelées "c̲h̲e̲v̲a̲u̲x̲" ?
```

Ici, on en compte 13, mais pourquoi ne pas propager le redéfinition plus en avant ? A noter que de plus la phrase fait référence au "chevaux" à cause du "également".

Avec la définition rétroactive:

```
Un paysan possède trois vaches, dix c̲h̲e̲v̲a̲u̲x̲ et vingt brebis.
Combien a-t-il de c̲h̲e̲v̲a̲u̲x̲ si les vaches sont également appelées "c̲h̲e̲v̲a̲u̲x̲" ?
```

Ca garde tout son sens à l'image de :

```
Un paysan possède trois bergers allemands, dix chiens et vingts brebis.
Combien a-t-il de chiens sil les bergers allemands sont également appelés des "chiens"?
```

Tout semble concomitant avec 10 comme réponse.

Pouvez-vous trancher ?

Comment: La réponse "attendue" ne serait-elle pas plutôt 3 du coup ? Dans l'énoncé, il y a 10 vaches et 3 chevaux et dans le raisonnement, c'est l'inverse...

Comment: En effet, j'ai mis à jour la question. Mauvaise retranscription !

Comment: Je n’ai pas de référence & l’importance de “signifié/signifiant" m’échappe, donc en commentaire je ose dire que, comme écrite, la dernière phrase du problème ne sert qu’a définir les termes du problème (par son auteur, qui a ce droit) et avec les termes du problème si clairement (mais bizarrement) définis, 13 est ma réponse. Si (et seulement si) la 2eme phrase était plutôt genre «Combien a-t-il de chevaux si le paysan ne connait pas la diff entre vache et chevaux & appelle ses vaches comme ‘chevaux’», ma réponse serait 10 car, comme vous dites, une vache ne devient pas un cheval pour autant.

Comment: Ce n'est pas un problème de français. Pas même vraiment de linguistique, il s'agit d'un problème d'axiomatisation. Si les vaches sont appelées chevaux dans un autre monde que celui de la question elle-même (par exemple celui du monde dont elle parle), l'hypothèse additionnelle ne change rien et la réponse est 10 comme proposé. Si l'hypothèse s'applique au texte de la question (hypothèse exceptée…) alors « chevaux » possède deux sens et la question est ambiguë, il n'y a pas moyen d'y répondre. Je ne vois pas comment comprendre différence entre signifié et signifiant intervient ici.

Answer (score 2):

Problème de *[syllogisme](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllogisme)* qui dépend du domaine de la réponse ?

- Mathématiquement *13* :  3 V + 10 C + 20 B ; V = C ; 13 C + 20 B.
- Philosophiquement : dix chevaux, trois pseudo chevaux et vingt brebis.
- Au café du commerce : "Mimile t'es pas encore assez bourré, tu raisonnes comme un énarque, remets ta tournée et tu résonneras comme un tambour."
- Les voisins du paysan : Il a des hallucinations, comment qu'il va traire treize chevaux ?
- Alice : "Qu'on leur coupe la tête, à ces vache costumées en chevaux !"
- Nietzsche : Après la vache multicolore de Zarathoustra, voici que trois Centaures meuglant viennent chanter l'Opéra des OGM.
- Le poète relit ce qu'il y a avant le point d'interrogation, consulte l'oracle et répond in fine : "Que ce nœud de neurones soit *[tranché par l'antique méthode](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C5%93ud_gordien)*".

---

***EDIT***

On posait parfois cette question aux enfants :

> Vincent mit l'âne dans un près et s'en vint dans l'autre (prononcé pour que l'on puisse entendre *vingt, cent... mille* ânes dans un près et *cent-vingt* dans l'autre), combien cela fait de pattes et de queues ?

La vraie réponse est *quatre* et *une*, mais l'enjeu était de faire progresser le raisonnement sur l’intelligibilité multiple d'un texte.

*Il n'y a pas de réponse dans la réalité* à la question posée, pas de réponse non plus pour ce jeune paysan à qui un maître d'la ville (qui parlait 'pointu') parachuté dans son école posait cette question :

> - Si tu gardes vingt vaches et qu'une s'échappe, combien en ramènes-tu à l'étable ?
> - Je ne rentre pas à l'étable avant de l'avoir retrouvée, mon père me tuerait !

Ou bien la question est prise comme un jeu (pouvant être pédagogique) et c'est ainsi que la première partie de cette réponse à été écrite, ou la réponse intéresse les tondeurs d'œufs... vaste programme. Avec des *si* on met Paris en bouteille ! Ensuite on la boit, on est ivre de son génie, bien seul !

L'unification de : *signification, signifiant, signifié* rapproche *une réalité, sa formulation, ce qui est perçu* ; et non "imagination pervertissant une réalité par la distorsion des mots associés".

*Trancher*, oui, mais trancher *raisonnablement* la question par l'absurdité de l'hypothèse... ou changer de domaine, passer des pseudos math à la poésie ou à la mise en mouvement d'un art pour éclairer l'illusion manifeste.

Comment: Encore un vote négatif qui sombre dans l'oubli, tans pis pour lui !

Answer (score 1):

Il me semble que les attentes annoncées ne font pas sens d'un point de vue linguistique non plus. Si les vaches sont également appelées "chevaux" dans la langue en question, alors CHEVAL est un hyperonyme pour les vaches et les chevaux et il est normal de pouvoir en compter 13. Et pour revenir à la question du signifiant/signifié, dans ce cas, le signifiant cheval correspond à plusieurs signifiés d'où l'ambiguïté.

Pour prendre un exemple simple et différent, si un couple possède deux chiens et trois chiennes, combien possèdent-ils de chiens ? Pour la plupart des locuteurs, il s'agira de compter le nombre d'animaux de la catégorie CHIEN quel qu'en soit le sexe : 5.

Bien sûr, une partie des réponses ne comptera que les chiens mâles et certaines réponses seront 2. Et comme toujours dans ce genre d'enquête, il y aura d'autres réponses plus ou moins farfelues...

Comment: L'hyperonyme est encore une possibilité en effet. De toute façon l'énoncé n'est pas clair.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez - *Hyperonymie* pour ongulés : mouton et vache avec sabot fendu (exclu du regroupement) et cheval sur un seul doigt,  pourquoi pas ; appliquer la sémantique à cette famille biologique de mammifères sélectionnée pour l'agriculture donne l'impression d'un capilotractage.